# Combine posts and postmeta

Tags: wpdb

I need to get all post ids, post_titles and the according meta_value which is "featured" for a custom post_type. I think I need to do a join, but I don't know how they work.. Could anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_posts builtin function and change meta_key and meta_value

```
$args = array(
  'meta_key'         => 'YOUR_META_KEY',
  'meta_value'       => 'featured',
  'post_type'        => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE',
  'post_mime_type'   => '',
  'post_parent'      => '',
  'author'     => '',
  'author_name'    => '',
  'post_status'      => 'publish',
  'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$posts_array = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $posts_array as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<li>
    <span><?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?></span>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; 

// MUST Reset
wp_reset_postdata();
```

NOTE: DO NOT modify local foreach variable [$post]

for more details see [WordPress get_posts function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'name_of_field_with_featured_as_value',
            'value'   => 'featured',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()) :
    //usual loop code but with $query as above, note that post related functions are called as usual, e.g. simply the_title(), not $query->the_title()
endif;
```

Comment: DO NOT use WP_Query when you can use get_posts because it could change the main query and will need to be reset with wp_reset_query .. WordPress Advice

Comment: i don't think it changes the main query, you are creating a new instance of it.

Comment: In get_posts you should use [ wp_reset_postdata ]  and in WP_Query you should use [wp_reset_query] which must be limited when you can use get_posts

Comment: it has to be called after query_posts https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query